# Camel to D pattern dosen't keep the encoded part of the url when invoking a http endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, urlencode, spring-camel, camel-rest

I exposed a web service on Apache Camel.

Endpoint:
[https://company.aaaa.com/persons/{zone}/{personId}/equipments?equipmentId=value](https://company.aaaa.com/persons/%7Bzone%7D/%7BpersonId%7D/equipments?equipmentId=value) (named webservice A)
The web service A takes this parameters:

-zone de type string : path param

-personId de type integer : path param

-equipmentId de type string : request param

The web service A do many things and call many other web services but to keep things simple, I will focus only on the web service that fails.

so if the equipmentId is not null, the web service A call a web service B with this endpoint
[https://company.bbbb.com/persons/{zone}/{personId}/equipments/{equipmentId}](https://company.bbbb.com/persons/%7Bzone%7D/%7BpersonId%7D/equipments/%7BequipmentId%7D)

**It works when the equipmentId dosen't contain `/` and I got the right response.**

**But My problem is** if `equipmentId` contains `/` caracter for example (equipmentId = AQCz/gIAJWsDACivB==)
It will fails with 404 not found because he can't find the resource.

So I encoded the `equipmentId`, store it in an exchange property called  `equipmentEncoded`
and use the `toD` camel pattern to invoke the endpoint.

Then when I called the web service A :

```
https://company.aaaa.com/persons/zone/56809546/equipments?equipmentId=AQCz/gIAJWsDACivB==
```

I got an error 404 : Failed to invoke the endpoint `https://company.bbbb.com/persons/zone/56809546/equipments/AQCz/gIAJWsDACivB==`

When debugging : I do have an exchange property `equipmentEncoded` with right value encoded `AQCz%2FgIAJWsDACivB%3D%3D`
But I don't know why `toD` don't keep the encoded value of the exchange property `equipmentEncoded`

This is the algorithme of the web  service A : (Just the part that generates error)

```
  .process(setEquipmentIdPropertyProcessor)
                .choice()
                    .when(exchangeProperty(TestConstants.EQUIPMENT_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_EXIST).isEqualTo(1))
                        .process(exchange -> {
                            var t = true;
                        })
                        .toD(getHTTPEndpointURL(companyBEndpoint, "persons/${header." + TestConstants.HEADER_ZONE_PARAM + "}/"
                                + "${header." + TestConstants.HEADER_PERSON_ID_PARAM + "}/" + "equipments/"
                                +"${exchangeProperty." + TestConstants.EQUIPMENT_ENCODED + "}" ))
                .endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                    .process(exchange -> {
                        var t = true;
                    })
```

This the code of the processor setEquipmentIdPropertyProcessor

```
@Component
  public class SetEquipmentIdPropertyProcessor implements Processor {
  @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
      String equipmentParamValue = 
       (String)exchange.getIn().getHeader(TestConstants.HEADER_EQUIPMENT_PARAM);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(equipmentParamValue)){
        exchange.setProperty(TestConstants.EQUIPMENT_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_EXIST, 1);
        String equipmentEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(equipmentParamValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        exchange.setProperty(TestConstants.EQUIPMENT_ENCODED, equipmentEncoded);
    } else {
        exchange.setProperty(TestConstants.EQUIPMENT_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_EXIST, 0);
    }

}
```

}

so in the class `SetEquipmentIdPropertyProcessor`  when the `equipmentId` request param is filled, I encode the `equipmentId` param and store the value  in an `exchange property`.

Here is the code of the method getHttpEndpointURL to construct the url:

```
    public String getHTTPEndpointURL(final EndpointProperty endpointConf, final String 
             uriPath) {
    return endpointConf.getUrl() +
            endpointConf.getPath() +
            uriPath + "?bridgeEndpoint=true";

}
```

Here is the code of the classe TestConstants

```
public class TestConstants {
public static final String HEADER_ZONE_PARAM = "zone";
public static final String HEADER_PERSON_ID_PARAM = "personId";
public static final String HEADER_EQUIPMENT_PARAM = "equipment";
public static final String EQUIPMENT_ENCODED = "equipmentEncoded"; }
```

**I would like that Camel invokes this url** https://company.bbbb.com/persons/zone/56809546/equipments/AQCz%2FgIAJWsDACivB%3D%3D

instead of invoking this one : https://company.bbbb.com/persons/zone/56809546/equipments/AQCz/gIAJWsDACivB==

Comment: have you tried with .to() ?

Comment: I have to use toD camel pattern because the endpoint is dynamic and it is constructed based to webservice param personId, zone ... which they change their values